# MVC4 Bind DataTable request parameters to action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to implement server-side paging and sorting for jquery-datatable.
but the issue is I'm not able to bind data posted by datatable to my action model
to do sort and filter

Here is the data posted by jquery-datatable ajax request

```
draw:5
columns[0][data]:FirstName
columns[0][name]:FirstName
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:LastName
columns[1][name]:LastName
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
......
columns[n][data]:Position
columns[n][name]:Position
columns[n][searchable]:true
columns[n][orderable]:true
columns[n][search][value]:
columns[n][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:1
order[0][dir]:desc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

and my action method is:

```
 public JsonResult GetGridData(GridFilter filter)
{ ....}

and my model classes are

    public class GridFilter
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }

        public List<ColModel> columns { get; set; }
        public List<Order> order { get; set; }

        public int start {get;set;}

        public int length {get;set;}

        public search search { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColModel
    {
        public string data { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public string searchable { get; set; }

        public string orderable { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string dir { get; set; }
        public string column { get; set; }
    }

    public class search
    {
        public string value {get;set;}
        public string regex {get;set;}
    }
```

How can I make data bind properly using default mvc model binders are a custom one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your model properties have the same data types as defined [here.](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Also you have gone one level too far with your models.They are sent as individual parameters so you don't need the `GridFilter` model, they should be received like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetGridData(List<ColModel> columns, List<Order> order, Search search, int? start, int? length, int? draw)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Try adding `[HttpPost]` to your action

Comment: Apologies some of your data types are incorrect in your models

Comment: I updated my answer with a link that will tell you what data types to use for each property